# which thread a BeginInvoke's callback of a asynchronous delegate is in?

Tags: c#, winforms

Which thread a BeginInvoke's callback of a asynchronous delegate is supposed to be in?
UI thread or a Thread Pool thread.

for example

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Func<string> func1 = LoadingDada;
    func1.BeginInvoke(IsDone, func1);
}


string LoadingDada()
{
    Thread.Sleep(10000);  //simulated a long running
    x = Thread.CurrentThread.Name;
    return "str_100000";
}

string IsDone(IAsyncResult a) 
{
    var loadingDataReturn = (Func<string>)a.AsyncState;
    string rr = loadingDataReturn.EndInvoke(a);

    textBox1.Text = rr;
}
```

Comment: how to put code in a block? Func<string> can't display.

Comment: Code is indented 4 spaces (or more). Try selecting your code and clicking the CODE button (the 0s and 1s).

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `BeginInvoke` *on the delegate*, so it will be a pool thread. If you called `BeginInvoke` *on a control* it would be the UI thread.

It is unfortunate that `BeginInvoke` means almost the exact opposite in these two scenarios.

Comment: @Mark, I can update UI Control in IsDone(). so it is in UI thread?

Comment: Hope someone's still listening... I'm afraid I find the answer a bit confusing.

I would phrase the question differently:Is the callback called on the same thread as where the original BeginInvoke call was made, or is it called from the thread used by BeginInvoke to execute whatever was specified?

Comment: @Mike when BeginInvoke is used on a delegate, the callback will always happen on a different thread - a worker / pool thread.